# How to Get Last Id MySQL in Scrapy?

Tags: mysql, scrapy

This is the snippet of the code in my pipeline. And I want to get the last inserted ID

```
result = tx.execute("INSERT INTO articles(title, description, url) VALUES ('" + item['title'] + "', '" + it    em['description'] + "', '" + item['url'] + "')"
          )
print('#RESULT', result)
```

In here, the result printed 1L.

My Purpose: My article as many images, so I want to save them in a different table. By getting the last id of the article, I can use it as a foreign keys to the images table.

How do I do it? Or You have any other practical solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tx.lastrowid` to get the last row ID inserted

Comment: @Vicheanak, you can accept if it resolves the problem!

Comment: @Rebecca Close: How did you know about it? Can you provide the link to the document? That would be appreciated.